# Cannot feed value of shape (75, 4) for Tensor 'x:0', which has shape '(?, 120)'

Tags: python, neural-network, reshape, shapes

I am trying to apply ELM on tabular data instead of on image dataset. Where I am trying to assign input and output nodes to some placeholder of 
shape

`shape of __a  [None, 120(input node)]`

`the shape of __b [None, 120(output node)]`

The shapes of my input data are

`the shape of y [75,4]
the shape of z [45,4]`

What I am trying to do is

`self.__sess.run(self.__init_train, feed_dict={self.__a: y, self.__b: z})`

Where __a and __b supposed to be the shape of total dataset rows which is 120 in my case.
but I am splitting the dataset on run-time, and passing only 75 rows at first, for training.

I am getting below error

`Cannot feed value of shape (75, 4) for Tensor 'x:0', which has shape '(?, 120)'`

the same code works well for cipher 100 dataset, with input nodes shape of 32*32*4 but not in my current scenario.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: this is a type mismatch, you have to change to model to fit your data, or change your data according to the model.

Comment: @phalanx I can't change the data for my need, because i' trying to create an algorithm that works for most datasets, however i have no idea of what do you mean by saying changing model to fit my data, as i haven't created any model yet, it's just that what i'm trying to create is, sending 75 rows for training and weight initialization

Comment: change `__a  [None, 120(input node)]` to `__a  [75(input node), None]` and the `__b` accordingly. this way the error will gone but i am not sure about rest of your network and how it works